# imagemin-webpack-plugin installation failing in windows machine

Tags: node.js, reactjs

x Error: pngquant failed to build, make sure that libpng-dev is installed
npm ERR! pngquant-bin@5.0.2 postinstall: `node lib/install.js`

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Stack Overflow. Your question must, at the very least, contain a question, not just an error message. Please visit https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: the answer is there in your error message: `make sure that libpng-dev is installed`

Comment: in windows machine not able to install libpng-dev.

Answer (score 0):

welcome to Stackoverflow. This is not a proper question, but I will go ahead and do my best to answer.

Have you followed the installation guide listed on their NPM page?

> Make sure you have node.js and npm installed, and that the pngquant
>   binary is in your PATH, then run:

```
npm install pngquant
```

Also as the error says, you need to make sure that libpng-dev is installed

```
npm install libpng-dev
```

Comment: libpng-dev is not npm package. need to install libpng-dev in window system. please give any other solution.